# Мне необходимо вывести предложение в консоль

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Я написал код, однако он выводит не текст, а какую-то ересь: `<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="98b82186-f957-4921-a2b9-df39c464d402", element="82cdb8b8-b7fc-460f-b169-1fd09e5d4f44")>.`

Вот мой код:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/Users/rus01/Desktop/webdriver/geckodriver')
znachenie = input()
driver.get('https://text.skynet.center')

text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="editorjs"]/div[1]')

text.send_keys(znachenie)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/section/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button').click()

final = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ql-editor')
print(final)
```

Прошу помощи у знающих людей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь "вывести" сам найденый элемент. Вместо этого, вам нужно "вывести" текст:

```
print(final.text)
```